# How to save data from different children to a single array in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

Here I have three components. Whenever I click the button in any of the child components (`First` and `Second`) the parent (`Test`) component should display text entered into the child component. The problem is that whenever I click the button of other child component a new array is created with data from that particular component.
Here's the code:

Test component:

```
function Test() {
    const [ChildData , setChildData] = useState('');
    
    console.log(ChildData)

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div>
            {ChildData? <div>{ChildData.map((data)=>{return <div>{data}</div> })}</div>:null }
        </div>
        <First passChildData={setChildData}/>
        <Second passChildData={setChildData}/>       
    </div>
  )
}
```

First component:

```
function First(props) {

  const [Data, setData] = useState('');
  const [Items, setItems] = useState('')

  const handlechange = (e)=>{
    setData(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleClick = ()=>{
    if(Data != ''){
      setItems((prevData)=>{
        const newData = [...prevData,Data];
        props.passChildData(newData)
        return newData
      })
      setData('')
    }else{
      console.log("enter something")
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>First</h1>
        <input type="text" onChange={handlechange} value={Data}/>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
        {Data}
        <div>{Items? <div>{Items.map((item)=>{return <div>{item}</div> })}</div>:null }</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Second component:

```
function Second(props) {
  
  const [Data, setData] = useState('');
  const [Items, setItems] = useState('')

  const handlechange = (e)=>{
    setData(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleClick = ()=>{
    if(Data != ''){
      setItems((prevData)=>{
        const newData = [...prevData,Data];
        props.passChildData(newData)
        return newData
      })
      setData('')
    }else{
      console.log("enter something")
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Second</h1>
        <input type="text" onChange={handlechange} value={Data}/>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
        {Data}
        <div>{Items? <div>{Items.map((item)=>{return <div>{item}</div> })}</div>:null }</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I expect is:

- When I enter "What" into the `First` component;
- Then "is" into the `Second` component;
- Then "your" into the `First` component
- Then "name?" in `Second` component

I want "What is your name?" (Doesn't matter if it's in different divs or lines; I want every single item to be displayed in the order it was entered) to be shown inside the parent (`Test`) component.

Comment: Are the First and Second components identical except for their `<h1>` headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would not have two components - `First` and `Second` - that are nearly identical except for their headings; I would have a single component with `heading` as a prop.

Second, I would use a `<form>` with an `onSubmit` handler instead of a `<button>` with an `onClick` handler because this will allow the user to add an item by, for example, pressing [Enter] while the input field has focus.

Third, I would use the `useEffect` hook to listen for changes in the `First` component to the `Items` array and then call the `passChildData` prop function when there is a change. Note that variables that are to reference arrays should be initialized with empty arrays, for example: `const [Items, setItems] = useState([])`.

The final code looks like:

```
function Test() {
  const [ChildData, setChildData] = useState([]);

  const setItem = (newItem) => {
    setChildData([...ChildData, newItem]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div>
          {ChildData.map((data, index) => <div key={index}>{data}</div>)}
        </div>
        <First heading="First" passChildData={setItem}/>
        <First heading="Second" passChildData={setItem}/>
    </div>
  )
}

function First(props) {
  const [Data, setData] = useState('');
  const [Items, setItems] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    props.passChildData(Data);
  }, [Items])

  const handlechange = (e)=>{
    setData(e.target.value)
  }
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (Data === '') {
        console.log('enter something');
    } else {
        setItems([...Items, Data]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{props.heading}</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" onChange={handlechange} value={Data}/>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
          {Data}
        </form>
        <div>
          {Items.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item}</div>)}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/hzLsye5f/) for reference.

Comment: identical Components , because i just playing around with these things. And this was an playground only to learn how data flows.

Comment: @HamdanSalih : Understood. Is my post helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mutating the whole state within every component. In other words, you don't use `prevData`.
I would change the state in `onClick` method of First and Second component, like this:

```
setItems((prevData)=>{
        const newData = [***...prevData***, ...Items,Data];
        props.passChildData(newData)
        return newData
      })
```